# Issue with Gradle 6.8.3 in STS 4.6 - Tooling API version older than 3.0 was removed in Gradle 5.0

Tags: gradle

I'm using STS 4.6 and getting below error while using Gradle 6.8.3. I was able to build project using Gradle 4.10 but for JDK 11 I had to upgrade Gradle version. Please assist how to resolve this

```
Support for clients using a tooling API version older than 3.0 was removed in Gradle 5.0. You are currently using tooling API version 2.2.1. You should upgrade your tooling API client to version 3.0 or later.
```

Comment: Could you post your build.gradle?

Comment: Due to company's strict policy unfortunately I can not upload the entire file but let me see if I can upload some of the lines..

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by uninstalling 'Gradle IDE' plugin provided by Pivotal and installing 'Eclipse Buildship plugin for Gradle' - Refer [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/issues/110)